# Failed to access wordpress rest api from remote machine using postman to get response in JSON

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to setup wordpress on my mac. I installed successfully and tried to get response in json . It worked : like

```
  api : http://localhost:8888/<site>/wp-json/wp/v2/pages
```

i.e. site is name of wordpress folder.

and response :

```
 [
 {
"id": 6,
"date": "2017-06-04T19:12:37",
"date_gmt": "2017-06-04T19:12:37",
"guid": {
  "rendered": "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/?p=6"
},
"modified": "2017-06-04T19:12:37",
"modified_gmt": "2017-06-04T19:12:37",
"slug": "test",
"status": "publish",
"type": "post",
"link": "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/2017/06/04/test/",
"title": {
  "rendered": "test"
},
"content": {
  "rendered": "<p>Vishal&#8217;s new post going viral</p>\n",
  "protected": false
},
"excerpt": {
  "rendered": "<p>Vishal&#8217;s new post going viral</p>\n",
  "protected": false
},
"author": 1,
"featured_media": 0,
"comment_status": "open",
"ping_status": "open",
"sticky": false,
"template": "",
"format": "standard",
"meta": [],
"categories": [
  1
], .....
```

Now I did setup wordpress in linux machine (Centos) on http url..

like wordpress site is accessible from remote machine by hitting url :

```
   http://x.x.x.x/<site>
```

i.e. site is name of wordpress folder

but when I am trying to hit

```
    http://x.x.x.x/<site>/wp-json/wp/v2/pages
```

then it results me :

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /<site>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts was not found on this server.</p>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me here. i am using latest version of wordpress setup.

permalink setting:

```
  Plain http://x.x.x.x/<site>/?p=123
  Day and name  http://x.x.x.x/<site>/2017/06/14/sample-post/
  Month and name    http://x.x.x.x/<site>/2017/06/sample-post/
  Numeric   http://x.x.x.x/<site>/archives/123
  Post name http://x.x.x.x/<site>/sample-post/
  Custom Structure  
  http://x.x.x.x/<site>  
 /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

default I choosed Custom-Structure

Comment: what is your permalink setting? that wp json url not worked for plain / default permalink

Comment: I choosed custom Structure

Comment: I used wordpress folder name is merchant ... like :
http://x.x.x.x/merchant

@RyanAW

Comment: try with these following url `http://yourwebsite/?rest_route=/wp/v2/`

Comment: thanks @RyanAW it is working .. 
I tried url : http://yourwebsite/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts 
it gives response in json ..

Comment: @RyanAW can you help on how can I pass filters ..like 
http://yourwebsite/?rest_route=/wp/v2/media

this will give me all media. If I want only media where title = "coffee"

Comment: I think you should create a new question so the others also can help your problem...